# Find a set of the most common numbers in a randomly filled array

Tags: c, compiler-errors, max

Good afternoon, and I have one question to ask about programming lottery in C language.

The requirements are:

1. Calculate each number's chance when if there are 46 balls labeled in each number in the box and there are 10K chances to pick one ball.
2. Then, print the number and number's chance on each item. The printed form must be like:

   ```
   Number 45: 251 times
   ```
3. Find six of the most found numbers and print them out. The printed form must be like:

   ```
   The most found were 45, 27, 8, 10, 12, 15
   ```

So my code was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10000
#define ballamount 6
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int fq[SIZE] = {0};
    int i, max = 0, maximum1 = 0, temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE i++)
    {
        ++fq[rand() % 45 + 1];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 45; i++)
    {
        printf("number %d: %d times\n", i + 1, fq[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ballamount i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++)
        {
            fq[j] = fq[0];
            if (fq[j] > temp)
            {
                temp = fq[j];
                max = j;
            }
        }
        fq[i] = max;
        fq[max] = 0;
        printf("Maximum number is %d.\n", max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I cannot find the path to solve this stuff. How can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You tagged this `compiler-errors`. What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: You have a typo: `for (i = 0; i < ballamount i++)` you're missing the `;` before `i++`

Comment: The same problem here: `for (int i=0; i < SIZE i++)`

Comment: The array doesn't need  `SIZE` elements, it only needs 46 elements.

Comment: regarding: `int i, max = 0, maximum1 = 0, temp = 0;` and `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE i++)`  the variable `i` in the declarations line is being shadowed by the variable `i` in the `for()` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, `fq` contains the number of times a given index is randomly selected, you already have that, you just have to select the six largest values in the array, minor tweaks to your code will render you the correct result.

Your code fixed, including `;` typos, in the for loops, with comments:

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dqsrcYxfW)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h> // for the seed

#define SIZE 10000
#define ballamount 6
```

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // add a seed for your random number generator
    int fq[46] = {0}; // the array only needs 46 elements
    int max = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) // was missing ;
    {
        ++fq[rand() % 46]; // if it's from 1 to 46, use index 0 to 45 
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++) // index 0 to 45
    {
        printf("number %d: %d times\n", i + 1, fq[i]);
    }
    printf("The most found balls were: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < ballamount; i++) // was missing ;
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 46; j++)
        {
            if (fq[j] > temp)
            {
                temp = fq[j];
                max = j;
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", max + 1); // adding 1, index starts at 0
        fq[max] = 0;
        temp = 0; // reset temp after the loop
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
number 1: 194 times
number 2: 187 times
...
...
The most found balls were: 28 30 43 5 29 12
```

Comment: this has the same problem as the OPs posted code.  I.E. the initial declaration for variable `i` is being shadowed by the variable `i` in the `for()` loops

Comment: @user3629249, I hadn't notice that, well spotted